# GET / MySql Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm a newbie to mysql, so is there possible to GET data by row and GET data from all of my tables in one function?
**here's my code:**

```
getAllBooksModel: function (detail) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (detail) {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM books WHERE ?', [detail], function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(res)
          console.log(res)
        }
      })
    } else {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM books', function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(res)
          console.log(res)
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: Please add actual code instead of image.

Comment: ok, my bad dude, I'm also new in stackoverflow

Comment: Why not do the logic of deciding to get one or many outside of your actual Promise and then just execute one query to  your database?

Comment: @Chris great idea, I'll try it bud!